# Design pattern para projeto WebApi

Tags: web-service, design-pattern, asp.net-web-api

Preciso criar um projeto com WebAPI para consumir algumas *procedures* de um banco SQL remoto, por exemplo: `sp_retornaProdutos(1)` transformando isso em `/produtos/1` e retornando o resultado em *JSON*.

Pensei em criar *models* de *request* e *response*, dessa forma:

```
// Model para envio de parâmetros
public class ProdutoReq
{
    int id;
}

// Model para retorno do resultado
public class ProdutoRes
{
    int id;
    string nome;
    string descricao;
    decimal preco;
}
```

Gostaria de saber como vocês indicam construir essa aplicação, qual padrão de projeto utilizar?

Comment: Em qual linguagem? Java? C#?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/)
ele é um micro framework desenvolvido em `php`.

Exemplo de uso:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

$app->run();
```

Onde esta echo você pode colocar o seu SQL para dar um retorno. quando chamar a api, mais documentação em: [Docs.Slim](http://docs.slimframework.com/)

e um how to [Aprenda a usar o RESTful com PHP e Slim Framework](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/aprenda-a-usar-o-restful-com-php-e-slim-framework/)